# Database displaying []?

Tags: java, sql, swing, ms-access, jtable

Im made a program that takes strings from the whole jtable and populates my database in ms access. But whenever i run it my database has [] instead of the actual information. How do i take the information in my jtable and use that to populate my database?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class apples extends JPanel {
static JTable table;
static JFrame frame;
static apples a;
 static ActionListener actionListener;
 static ActionListener actionListenerImport;
 static ActionListener actionListenerAddrow;
 static String[] columns = {"Fname","Lname"};
 static String[][] data;
 static DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    table = new JTable(model);
    frame = new JFrame();
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 200));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.add(jps);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    panel.add(b1, c);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("Import");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    panel.add(b2, c);

    JButton b3 = new JButton("Add Row");
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    panel.add(b3, c);


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jps, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();


    actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TestDatabase");
                Statement s = con.createStatement();
                String deleteRows = "DELETE FROM Table1";
                s.execute(deleteRows);
                ArrayList<String> numdata = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> numdata2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                String insertTable = ("INSERT INTO Table1(Fname,Lname) VALUES('"+numdata+"','"+numdata2+"');");//get data from table and put in here

                for (int count = 0; count < model.getRowCount(); count++){
                      numdata.add(model.getValueAt(count, 0).toString());
                      for (int count1 = 0; count1 < model.getRowCount(); count1++){
                          numdata2.add(model.getValueAt(count, 1).toString());
                          s.executeUpdate(insertTable);
                    }
                }




            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
            }

        }
    };
    actionListenerImport = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TestDatabase");
                Statement s = con.createStatement();
                String selTable = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
                s.execute(selTable);
                ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();

                while((rs!= null) && (rs.next())) {
                    model.addRow(new String[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)});
                }



            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    };
    actionListenerAddrow = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            model.addRow(new String[]{"",""});
        }
    };


    b1.addActionListener(actionListener);
    b2.addActionListener(actionListenerImport);
    b3.addActionListener(actionListenerAddrow);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> numdata = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> numdata2 = new ArrayList<String>();
String insertTable = ("INSERT INTO Table1(Fname,Lname) VALUES('"+numdata+"','"+numdata2+"');");
```

You are attempting to add an ArrayList into your database. You can't just change the values of numdata and numdata2 in your loop.

Instead you need to create a dynamic SQL statement. The easiest way to do this is to use a `PreparedStatement`, then you can dynamically change the parameters. The code would be something like:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(Fname,Lname) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

for (int count = 0; count < model.getRowCount(); count++)
{
    String numdata = model.getValueAt(count, 0).toString();
    String numdata2 = model.getValueAt(count, 1).toString();
    stmt.setString( 1, numdata );
    stmt.setString( 2, numdata2 );
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: ive used your folowing code but id does not populate the second column in my database.

Comment: Then I've proven that the basic structure is correct. It is now up to you to do some debugging to determine what the exact problem is. We can not do all the work for you. We don't have access to your database or program. Maybe your SQL is wrong. Maybe the data is wrong (did you print out the values from the table model before you attempt to update the database.